# How to check is ALL elements of a collection exists in another collection in HQL

Tags: hibernate, collections, mapping, hql

i have a Course entity that have a mapped collection of Skill entities. now i want to check thru HQL if all the elements of course.skills collection exists in another collection which i will be passing as a parameter in the query.

i can check if one element is already in the other collection using IN statement, but i can't seem to figure out how to check is ALL elements are present.

hope someone could help me out. thanks!

Comment: can you give some code sample of what you have tried... since question is not that clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would love to find a more elegant solution to this problem, but I solve it with such a query:

```
select course from Course course
where not exists (
    select skill.id from Skill skill
    where skill.id in :setOfSkillIdsToHave
    and skill.id not in (
        select courseSkill.id
        from Course course2
        inner join course2.skills courseSkill
        where course2.id = course.id))
```

or,

```
select course from Course course
where :numberOfSkillsToHave = (
    select count(skill.id)
    from Course course2
    inner join course2.skills courseSkill
    where courseSkill.id in :setOfSkillIdsToHave
    and course2.id = course.id)
```